# Comparision between two Strings in ClickHouse

Tags: clickhouse

I have a table `my_table` in a database `my_db` with a `String` column named `IpAddr`.

The following query:

```
select 
    IpAddr, 
    lower(IpAddr), 
    IpAddr = lower(IpAddr) 
from my_db.my_table 
where IpAddr = '10.144.145.159' 
limit 1
```

produces the following output:

```
IpAddr          lower(IpAddr)   equals(IpAddr, lower(IpAddr))
10.144.145.159  10.144.145.159  1
```

**The question is how may I interpret that number 1 as the result of the comparision?**

Does it mean that the `String` and its `lowered` counterpart are not the same? Or is it exactly the oposite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out that `1` means `true`, because the following query:

```
select 
    IpAddr, 
    name, 
    IpAddr = name 
from my_db.my_table 
where IpAddr = '10.144.145.159' 
limit 1

IpAddr         Name    equals(IpAddr, Name)
10.144.145.159 myName  0
```

the equals returns `0` for known `false` case, this is, because `10.144.145.159` and `myName` are not equal